# Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS is not going back to app

Tags: java, android, settings

I am trying to open Sound settings from my app

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS));
```

Sound Settings Activity displays without any issue.

Scenarios After Opening Sound settings page

1. When I press back button on my device, it is going back to my application.
2. when I click on back arrow button(top left), it is going to Settings Main Screen.

Issue:
I want to go back to my app when click on back icon also.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS), 100);
```

I have also tried this. but no result.

I am testing this on OnePlus 6 (Android 10 (Q))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an intent:
`Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS);`

Add these lines to your intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

then call `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Works fine, but the issue is if Settings is opened in background, then it is not working. If settings removed from stack, then working fine. Can we do something about this?

Comment: Add this flag `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);`

Comment: BTW, what will FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK do?

Comment: Is used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to disable the behavior of bringing an existing task to the foreground.